# docker: git clone results are not in local volume, args not expanding

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I am attempting to stand up a [PHP application](https://github.com/oat-sa/package-tao) via Docker.  I can get it working manually, but I am trying to improve it (make it more usable in a CI/CD environment) while following best practices (eg: single responsibility images, etc)

**TLDR:**

1. How can I reliably clone a git repo into a local shared volume?
2. How can I go from .env file to checking out a specific git tag?

**Issues:**

1. Cloning git into a path mapped to a local volume results in no data/files in my local path

   - I've found articles mentioning that mapping an empty volume earlier in a build process will cause the path to be empty (but I don't think that applies directly here.)
2. docker-compose config will show the correct value for `TAO_CODE_TAG`, but it fails (treated as empty) during checkout

   - I know, depending on how it is called in the dockerfile, shell expansion of variables may not occur.  However, I have seen working examples of it working with `RUN echo $var`?

**./.env**

```
PHP_VERSION=7.0
MYSQL_VERSION=5.7
APACHE_VERSION=2.4.32
TAO_CODE_TAG=v3.2-rc02
DB_ROOT_PWD=password ;-)
```

**./docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  git:
    build:
      context: './git/'
      args:
        TAO_CODE_TAG: ${TAO_CODE_TAG:?err}
    volumes:
      - ./tao-src/:/build
    container_name: git

  composer:
    image: composer/composer:php7  #  Would be nice to use tag from .env for php version
    command: install
    depends_on:
      - git
    volumes:
      - ./tao-src/:/app
    container_name: composer

  php:
    build:
      context: './php/'
      args:
        PHP_VERSION: ${PHP_VERSION:?err}
    depends_on:
      - composer
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - ./tao-src/:/var/www/html/
    container_name: php

  apache:
    build:
      context: './apache/'
      args:
        APACHE_VERSION: ${APACHE_VERSION:?err}
    depends_on:
      - git
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./tao-src/:/var/www/html/
    container_name: apache

  mysql:
    image: mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION:-latest}
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_ROOT_PWD:?err}
    container_name: mysql

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

**./apache/Dockerfile**

```
ARG APACHE_VERSION=""
FROM httpd:${APACHE_VERSION:+${APACHE_VERSION}-}alpine

# Copy apache vhost file to proxy php requests to php-fpm container
COPY demo.apache.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/demo.apache.conf
RUN echo "Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/demo.apache.conf" \
    >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

**./apache/demo.apache.conf**

```
ServerName localhost

LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule deflate_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Proxy .php requests to port 9000 of the php-fpm container
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/html/$1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Send apache logs to stdout and stderr
    CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
    ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
</VirtualHost>
```

**./git/Dockerfile**

```
ARG TAO_CODE_TAG
FROM alpine/git:1.0.4
RUN apk add git \
    && mkdir /build \
    && git clone https://github.com/oat-sa/package-tao /build \
    && cd /build \
    && git checkout tags/v3.2-rc02 # Should use val from .env!
VOLUME ["/build"] # Last in file so as to not "disappear" during build
```

**./php/Dockerfile**

```
ARG PHP_VERSION=""
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION:+${PHP_VERSION}-}fpm-alpine

# One run/layer as needed/able per recommendation in docs
# https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run
RUN apk update \
    # TAO requires zip support
    && apk add libzip-dev zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    # TAO requires pdo_mysql support
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    # TAO recommends opcache
    && docker-php-ext-install opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-configure opcache --enable-opcache \
    # Ensure a php.ini is present
    && mv $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini;
```

**PS:** Eventually, things such as using a secret server for secure credentials/etc, and use of the automated [install script](https://github.com/oat-sa/tao-core/blob/master/scripts/taoInstall.php) with the `.env` file, would be implemented as well.

Answer (score 1):

I can now get to the web install page.  So, for any interested...

## #1 - source/clone problem

I realized all I needed was the [compose.json](https://github.com/oat-sa/package-tao/blob/master/composer.lock) and the [index.php](https://github.com/oat-sa/package-tao/blob/master/index.php) files, which I can grab via [jsdeliver](https://www.jsdelivr.com/) in `ADD` [dockerfile statements](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add), followed by recursive chown/chmod for the new files in both php and apache `/var/www/html` folders.

**NOTE:** This doesn't really solve the problem of typically getting the source from github, but is sufficient for my actual/immediate needs for this particular codebase/project.

## #2 - tag problem

I solved the tag problem via...

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: './php/'
      args:
        PHP_VERSION: ${PHP_VERSION:?err}
        TAO_CODE_TAG: ${TAO_CODE_TAG:?err} # <-- IMPORTANT
```

**php/Dockerfile**

```
FROM composer/composer as Composed
ARG TAO_CODE_TAG # <-- IMPORTANT
RUN mkdir /build && cd /build
WORKDIR /build
ADD https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oat-sa/package-tao@${TAO_CODE_TAG}/composer.json /build/composer.json # <-- IMPORTANT
RUN composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-scripts --no-suggest --no-dev

# ...continues
```

## Etc

I am currently addressing the code/composer-install issue by duplicating a multi-stage build in both the php and apache derived image containers, as shown in the lines above, then...

**php/Dockerfile**

```
# continued...

ARG PHP_VERSION
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION:+${PHP_VERSION}-}fpm-alpine

RUN apk update \
    # ...etc.

# Gather composed packages from stage above
COPY --from=Composed /build /var/www/html/

# ...etc
```

Unfortunately, that is repeated for both the php and apache instances (requiring the code be baked into both.)  I am still investigating a way to create a shared source-only resource that would be accessible and mapped through a share (most likely).